# Video runs ok on w3school´s Try-It-editor website but does not open on its own on my site

Tags: html, video-streaming, html5-video

- I assembled the code below in order to play an hls stream feed from one of my sites.
- When I use the W3School´s Editor it runs very good, starts right away
  BUT
- When I run it from my site, the page opens showing a small black box with a play button (arrow)  inside,
- If a click on the play button then the video starts running (although  not full screen).
  -So I really have two issues, how to not have a blackbox so video starts rightaway like in W3schhol´s site and the second optional would be how to make it occupy the whole screen specially after using the meta viewport

...

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <head>
    <link
        href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/video.js/7.10.2/video-js.min.css"
        rel="stylesheet"
     />
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/video.js/7.10.2/video.min.js"> 
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <video-js id="vid1" controls preload="auto">
        <!-- Replace the src URL with the HLS manifest URL for a given video
         You can access this from the Cloudflare Stream dashboard or via the Stream API 
    -->
        <source
            src="https://vcp.myplaytv.com/promar/promar/playlist.m3u8"
            type="application/x-mpegURL"
        />
    </video-js>

    <script>
        const vid = document.getElementById('vid1');
        const player = videojs(vid);
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

...
Thank you
BTW  I also opened a free one website at W3Scools , ran the script and also comes up with the blackbox

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<link>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-link-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment: Rob when I took out the link, the whole page didnt wor, all sorts of information came out  Thanks anyway

Comment: I never said anything about taking out the link tag..

Comment: @Javier_Caceres **(1)** You **cannot autoplay** a video without first clicking some button on the web page. It works on W3Schools because you've clicked their "Run Code" button, so now any future `autoplay` command is accepted after that process. There is also browser **whitelisting** of certain websites (if you visit a page/site to play its video element enough times then it will autoplay by itself during any future visits).

Comment: @Javier_Caceres **(2)** You **cannot auto-fullscreen** on page load. It's a security issue. You'll have to add code that does: (a) listening for a "click" event on the "play" button then... (b) It runs the same function that clicking the  VideoJS fullscreen button would have done. the function would be something like `player.goFullscreen();` or such. You can search the source at the Github link for VideoJS. Try something and we'll try help you.

Comment: Thanks Rob, you are right, you didn`t say that I should take out the link tag.

Comment: Rob regarding (1) You cannot autoplay  what would be happening is that when I click run on the W3school`s page  its like clicking on a play button found sometimes at the bottom of a page or in a black box ?

Comment: Bob, is there a way to do what W3School does, that is, when a page is being loaded a click is ran and the video starts playing right away

Comment: I have run also some code that as soon as I open the page I see and image  or a frame of what is being played, but the video does not start,  Any idea on what could be happening

Comment: @Javier_Caceres _"As soon as I open the page I see an image (or a frame) of what is being loaded, but the video does not start"_ See if the modified [Answer by @Ivan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75864730/2057709) helps to play the video... PS: To answer your others: **(1)** W3Schools works because of the **autoplay** option. Note that autoplay does not work if user did not first click some button. So the "Run" button click on their web page just luckily makes the browser also accept the **autoplay** found in the `<video>` tag. You can get auto-play without any clicks if the video is **muted**.

Answer (score 1):

To video to start playing automatically, add `autoplay` attribute. Keep in mind that this will only work if there's no audio or `muted` attribute is present. Otherwise, user interaction is needed to start playin the video.

To make the `<video-js>` element fit the dimensions of parent container add `fluid="true"`.

So in your case, replace

```html
<video-js id="vid1" controls preload="auto">
```

with

```html
<video-js data-setup='{"fluid": true}' id="vid1" controls autoplay muted preload="auto">
```

See [video.js documentation](https://videojs.com/guides/options)